# ListItemText not displaying data

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to list data from array of objects, which had an embedded array. in Render I can console.log the data successfully but I cannot render the data in render.return()

sample data:

```
[ 
  { module: "Core", roles: ["role1", "role2", "role3"] }, 
  { module: "Asset", roles: ["Role1", "role2", "role3"] }
]
```

the code is:

```
      <ListItem>
        {
          (this.modules) && (
            this.modules.map((module, i) => {
              console.log(module.module)
              module.roles.map((role, j)=>{
                console.log(role)
                return (
                  <ListItemText key={j} style={{ padding: 0, margin: 0 }} secondary={module.module + " - " + role} />
                )
              })
            })
          )
        }
      </ListItem>
```

The ListItem and ListItemText is imported from material-ui

The console.log(module.module) shows me 
Core & Asset

The console.log(role) shows me 
role1
role2
role3
role1
role2
role3

This means the data is available until just before the return.
The listItemText is expected to display

```
Core - role1
Core - role2
Core - role3
Asset - role1
Asset - role2
Asset - role3
```

But is shows a blank screen

if I remove the module.roles.map() section the listItemText displays the module names.

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forget to return the `map` method to `dom`. Please find the modified solution below

```
 <ListItem>
    {
      (this.modules) && (
        this.modules.map((module, i) => {
          console.log(module.module)
          return module.roles.map((role, j)=>{
            console.log(role)
            return (
              <ListItemText key={j} style={{ padding: 0, margin: 0 }} secondary={module.module + " - " + role} />
            )
          })
        })
      )
    }
  </ListItem>
```

Comment: OMG I really forgot the basic step... my apologies…Thanks for guiding.